# Python subclass not recognizing inherited parent class

Tags: python, object, inheritance, subclass

I am struggling with my code, specifically subclasses. I have a parent class that when initialized will call its subclass to be used as an attribute, in the form of a list of objects. I have seen numerous post where a person forgets to call the `__init__()` of the parent. My issue is different in that the parent is calling the child class and I do not want to call it.

I am getting the following error:

```
NameError: name 'bundle' is not defined
```

I am confused because it is clearly defined as the parent class. Any ideas?

```
class bundle(object):
"""Main object to hold graphical information"""
    def __init__(self, size,nzone):
        self.size = size
        self.rows = math.sqrt(size)
        self.cols = math.sqrt(size)
        subchans = []
        r = 1
        c = 1 
        for i in range (1,self.size):
            subchans.append(bundle.subbundle(r,c,self.rows,self.cols))
            r += 1            
            if r > self.rows :
                r = 1
                c += 1
    class subbundle(bundle):
        """ Defines geometry to represent subbundle"""
        def  __init__(self, row, col, rows,cols):
```

Comment: The name `bundle` is not defined until *after* the class definition finishes, so `subbundle` cannot inherit from it *and* be a nested class.  It is not clear from the example why you would want `subbundle` to be either inherited or nested, though.

Comment: You cannot call any "subbundle" methods from "bundle" methods. It is the other way : a "subbundle" may call "bundle" methods. Subclassing is for specializing objects, not to engender childs

Comment: since you are doing the class nested inside of another class it doesnt know what `bundle` is, i think it would have to be `subbundle(self)` instead. But what you PROBABLY actually want is to make `subbundle(bundle)` a class of its own, that is not nested

Comment: Thanks to all, I am still getting used to OOP and I wanted to encapsulate since these two things are closely related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code, I got the error in the following line:

```
class subbundle(bundle):
```

That's because you are trying to **inherit** your `subundle` class from `bundle`. I don't know if that's what you actually want to do. Let's assume it is.

When Python tries to parse the `.py` file, it'll try to figure out the class hierarchy as soon as it sees `class bundle`. When the interpreter reaches `class subbundle(bundle)`, it doesn't know (yet) what `bundle` is. Move it to the same level than your `class bundle`:

```
class bundle(object):
    def __init__(self, size,nzone):
        self.size = size
        [ . . .]

class subbundle(bundle):
    """ Defines geometry to represent subbundle"""
    def  __init__(self, row, col, rows,cols):
        [ . . . ]
```

You'll stop seeing your current error and will start seeing a new one: `type object 'bundle' has no attribute 'subbundle'` That's because it's attempting to treat `bundle.subbundle` as a method of the `class bundle`, which is not. You might wanna change the code in the `bundle.__init__` to:

```
for i in range (1,self.size):
    subbundle_instance = subbundle(r, c, self.rows, self.cols)
    subchans.append(subbundle_instance)
```

**PS**: It's usually a good practice naming your classes with a capital letter (aka *CamelCase*) See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008#class-names